# Friendly URL not working in nested routes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, navigation, term-store, managed-navigation

I'm trying to enable friendly URLs on my Sharepoint Server 2013 site.

I've already enabled Managed Navigation for both Global Navigation and Current Navigation.
[image: Managed Navigation is Enabled]

I've already selected the Term Set I want to use, and even enabled tagging:

[image: Tagging and Term Set Navigation Enabled]

On each Term I've enabled Friendly URL Term Set navigation:

[image]

Added a Custom URL and the page it should display:

[image]

Yet when navigating to the above route (/Servicio_al_Cliente/Solicitudes) I get Page Not Found error.

I've read most of the articles I find, but all I see is how to enable Managed Navigation, and to select the Term Store, but nothing after. SharePoint Navigation does show the friendly URL, and attemps to redirect there, it just doesn't find it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have set up everything you need.
Here are a few things you can check:

1. The URL you use in "**Change target page for this term**" should be valid and browserable URLs to a **page**.

   It can be URL to any page, list views, Display forms included, but it needs to be first end with `.aspx` and then suffixes are also accepted.
2. There is a boundary for URLs from a different site collection.

   I have made a few tests and it works for a few site collections but returns error for others. And everything works just find if I use URLs from the current site collection.

[image]

Comment: It is a valid URL to a page, I even selected it by clicking "Browse" and going to the specific page "/Servicio_al_Cliente/Paginas/Estados-de-Cuenta.aspx".

Comment: @Danyx Have you tried other URLs? I assume it might have something to do with the symbols in the URL, but I cannot reproduce this issue. You can try with another page or another site collection and see if same issue happens.

Comment: which symbol? The '_'? I've tried with multiple pages in different subsites, will try creating a new collection.

Comment: @Danyx Yes, and also other symbols. One more question just in case: does the same issue happen if you use links from the parent site?